# why I don't call url from Http request when onCompletion

Tags: android

I want to call new url after My custom Music Player complete played but It do not call and send new url to my player. Help me please thank you.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
{
    playing = "Stopped";
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            now++;
            try
            {
                onCompleteURL = new URL(musicUrl[now]);
                onCompleteURLConnection = onCompleteURL.openConnection(); 
                onCompleteReadIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(onCompleteURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                onCompleteUrl = onCompleteReadIn.readLine();
                onCompleteReadIn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            waitingGetNextDataHandler1.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();
    waitingGetNextDataHandler1 = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            try 
            {
                /*mMediaPlayer.reset();
                sendHTTPRequest();
                startPlayer();*/
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(onCompleteUrl);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                playing = "Started";
                running = mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                playPauseImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(mMediaPlayer != null)
            {
                if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true)
                {
                    playPauseImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
                }
                else
                {
                    playPauseImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);
                }
                setValue();
            }
        }
    };
}
```